# How to track Radeon GPU temparature with windows command line?

Tags: c#, windows, gpu, temperature

I had knowledge in C# language and web application. I would like to know what is the window command to track the temperature of 4 RX 560 GPU which had installed on my PC.

I had find all of the resources in internet , but couldn't find any relate windows command line to track the temperature. Or if there is any DLL or API to track the temperature?

My purpose is to do a window services which keep track the temperature and push the temperature data to other server over the internet.

Appreciate if anyone can give me guidance.

Comment: What is a "Windows command" in your context?

Comment: Have you looked into working via power shell to get your desired result. This post talks about it -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21884264/retrieve-intel-pch-temperature-with-powershell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a similar question here on SO (although in that question it is about the CPU temperature): [**How to get CPU temperature?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195112/how-to-get-cpu-temperature)

The [answer of @Jens](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9564862/880511) provides information about [**Open Hardware Monitor**](http://openhardwaremonitor.org/). Although it first seems like an application, there's also an interface available.

More info from the site:

- [Documentation](http://openhardwaremonitor.org/documentation/) (what is supported by the interface, on the bottom is a link to a PDF with sample code)
- [Downloads](http://openhardwaremonitor.org/downloads/)
- [Source code on GitHub](https://github.com/openhardwaremonitor)